# MS Access object dependencies: Ok to use?

Tags: ms-access

I would like to use Access ability to show dependencies of an object.
I have read many times that Name AutoCorrect should be turned off at all times to avoid bad things to happen. But what about Object Dependencies ? It is quite a nice tool to have, and Access (2003) asks me "Track name autocorrect must be turned on". Is that dangerous ?
Thanks

Comment: You can turn on track name, but NOT turn on the Autocorrect feature. It is the autocorrect feature that can make a mess. The dependency feature ONLY requires the tracking to be turned on - you do NOT need (nor want) to turn on the autocorrect "name"  feature. So the tracking being turned on does NOT require you to turn on the autocorrect - and I think autocorrect name feature should be left off. So yes, you are free to turn on and LEAVE ON that feature. You are good to go as long as you keep in mind two features exist here - track name, and perform track name. (leave perform track off)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Name AutoCorrect can be risky.  See Allen Browne's page: [Failures caused by Name AutoCorrect](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-03.html)

Tracking object dependencies can be useful during development.  But it is not very thorough.  Use it in development if you find it helpful.  Be aware of the problems it can create.  And turn it off for production applications.

Comment: Perhaps also during development if anything is a little weird :)

Comment: Sorry, it is the perform name autocorrect feature that causes the issue, it is NOT the track name feature which is all the dependency checker requires. Please correct your post – tracking the corrections in an application has NEVER shown to damage or mess up the development process – it can be safely turned on – the “monster” in the closet is the PERFORM track auto correct which can be left off. Please edit your post to reflect this and to avoid confusing - point out that there is no problem with leaving track name on - it is the autocorrect feature that's the problem - not dependency checker

Comment: And please point out that the dependency feature is fine to use since one can use it without performing track name autocorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I run by default with Name AutoCorrect off.

But sometimes when I have a project where I need to do major renaming (usually it's a part of refactoring an old application in preparation for new development on the project), I will turn on Name AutoCorrect to do the renaming so that it propagates as many of the changes to object/table/field names as possible. Once the renaming is completed, I turn it off again.

It certainly shouldn't be on during normal development, and certainly not in a deployed application.